# Non-linear ODE: $(y')^2 + y = xy'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm sure it's staring at me, but how does one solve this?

$$ (y')^2 + y = xy' $$

Thanks.

Comment: That's [Clairut's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation). [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28y%27%29^2%2By%3Dxy%27) gives a clean solution step by step in this case, just click the 'show steps' button.

Comment: That should have been Clairaut, actually.

Comment: One solution is $y = x-1$?

Comment: @H.M.Šiljak: I think you meant [this one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28y%27%29%5E2%2By%3Dxy%27).

Comment: Ok, got it.
Differentiating both sides wrt x
2y'y'' + y' = y' + xy''
i.e.,
y''(2y'-x) = 0
which can now just be solved for each case in turn, y'' = 0 and 2y' = x

Thanks everyone.

Comment: So if you found solution, it is worth to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Gigili: strange, both links (yours and mine) look exactly the same to me :)

Comment: @H.M.Šiljak: Eh, how so? It should be $*(y')^2* + y = xy'$ as OP mentioned.

Comment: Got it - weird enough, the ^ in url didn't copy properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Differentiating both sides with respect to x:

$$2y^\prime y^{\prime\prime}+y^\prime =y^\prime+xy^{\prime\prime}$$

i.e., $y^{\prime\prime}(2y^\prime −x)=0$ which can now just be solved for each case in turn, $y^{\prime\prime}=0$ and $2y^\prime=x$

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Note that not every solution to $y'' = 0$ and $2y' = x$ automatically works because the differentiation step is not reversible. But it's easy to plug the solutions to those into the original equation and find out which solutions do work.